# How to change fillColor only between two series point on mouse click and drag?

Tags: html, css, angular, highcharts

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/745fL9a0>
```

In above fiddle there is functionality to click and drag to get price difference between two point along with that rectangle is drawn over chart. But I want behaviour as per below website where color only get fill in area.

https://www.tickertape.in/stocks/reliance-industries-RELI?checklist=basic

I have successfully modified the code for this but It's laggy Because, I am updating series and creating zones to change fillcolor between two point. Is there any otherway to do it ? I want exact click and drag behaviour as it is only website mentioned above please help

Answer (score 0):

You can colour the area above the line, which will be works as a mask. You will be able to achive that by i.e. setting the `threshold` to `Infinity` and adding `fillColor` for the `areaspline` series.

```
  plotOptions: {
    areaspline: {
      threshold: Infinity,
      fillColor: '#fff',
      ...
    }
  }
```

**API Refrence:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.threshold

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/57s8zr6d/

Comment: Thanks for answer, I did manage to do it, Now only thing I need is how do I also change the series line color of that hovered area, Any thoughts ?

Comment: As my colleague mentioned in the forum thread you created: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=48806 , this functionality is beyond the scope of support. If you would like to see such a feature feel free to create a feature request here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new/choose